# Does Heapsort work in time o(n log n) in the best case?

Tags: algorithms, runtime-analysis, sorting, lower-bounds, heap-sort

Is it possible for Heapsort to work in time $o(n\log n)$ on certain inputs?

For example in case of Insertion sort it is possible, however when it comes to Quickssort it is not possible.  What about Heapsort? I tried to find an input array such that Heapsort will be working in $o(n\log n)$.

I ask you is it possible? Some permutation? The same elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [paper: The Analysis of Heapsort by Schaffer and Sedgewick](ftp://ftp.cs.princeton.edu/techreports/1991/330.pdf) shows that

> Theorem 1: Heapsort requires that at least $\frac{1}{2} n \lg n - O(n)$ data moves for any heap composed of distinct keys.

and that

> Theorem 3: The *average* number of data moves required to Heapsort a random permutation of $n$ distinct keys is $\sim n \lg n$.

---

It also mentions that

> If equal keys are allowed, the best case is clearly linear [3]: consider the case of a heap with all keys equal.

The citation to [3] here is [TechReport: On Heapsort and its Dependence on Input Data](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=kekklYqTWfoC&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=on+heapsort+and+its+dependence+on+input+data&source=bl&ots=AK0Jfg_kVG&sig=FRyGLVa0IZJMK6IJTBxkThse5xo&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW6PzGqLfKAhUFWxoKHRvXCXAQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=on%20heapsort%20and%20its%20dependence%20on%20input%20data&f=false).